# Calculate Power for pump

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps, power

I did a Civil Engineering course some years ago and from my textbook I had a question on a pump with hoses. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a solution to this yet.

A pump feeds two hoses, each of which is 45 m long and is fitted with a nozzle. Each nozzle has a coefficient of velocity of 0.97 and discharges a 37.5 mm diameter jet of water at 24 m/s when the nozzle is at the same level as the pump. If the power lost in overcoming friction in the hoses is not to exceed 20 per cent of the hydraulic power available at the inlet end of the hoses,
calculate (a) the diameter of the hoses, taking f = 0.007, and (b) the power required to drive the pump if its efficiency is 70 percent and it draws its water supply from a level 3 m below the nozzle.

These are the calculations I have so far

a) Head lost in friction Hf = 4 * f * L * v^2/ D * 2g, where L = Length of hose, D = Hose diameter, v = hose velocity and f = friction coefficient

If H = Head at inlet to pump and hoses

Head at nozzle Hp = H − 4 * f * L * v^2/ D * 2g
or Hp = Head at inlet to hoses - frictional head loss in each hose.

If jet velocity = V and Cv = 0.97 Jet Velocity V=Cv √(2g ∗ Hp), where V = 24m/s

Hp = V^2/(2g ∗ Cv^2) = (24^2) / 2g * (0.97)^2, so Hp = 31.208 m

For continuity of flow, flow from hoses = flow from nozzle, so 1/4 Pi * D^2 * v = 1/4 * Pi * d^2 * V, where d = jet diameter

v = V * (d2/D2) = 24 *(0.0375)^2 / D^2 = v = 0.03375 / D2.

I have then put this in the frictional head loss formula 4 * f * L * V2/D * 2g = 4 * 0.007 * 45 * (0.03375 D^-2)^2 / (D * 19.62) = 1.43521875 ∗ 10−3 ∗ D−4/ D ∗ 19.62 = 1.43521875 ∗ 10−3/ (D5 ∗ 19.62).

Note 2g = 19.62

If power lost in overcoming friction in hoses is not to exceed 20 per cent of hydraulic power available at inlet end of hoses, then H = 5 * 4 * f * L * v^2/ D2g
so Hp = 5 ∗ (4 * f * L * v2/ D * 2g) - (4 * f * L * v^2/ D2g) = 4 * (4 * f * L * v^2/ D * 2g) = 4 * 1.43521875 * 10^-3/ (D^5 * 19.62) 
Hp = 5.740875*10^-3/ (D^5*2g)

So 2g * Hp = 5.740875 * 10^-3/ D^5 = 19.62 * 31.2018 = 612.1798m

D^5 = 5.740875 * 10^-3 / 612.179, so D = (5.740875 * 10^-3/ 612.1798)^0.2 = 0.09872m

**so Hose Diameter = 98.72 mm** 
**IN MY TEXT BOOK ANSWER WAS GIVEN AS 98.5mm, WOULD THIS BE DUE TO ROUNDING?**

(b) Power from pump P = w * Q * Hp, 
where w = unit weight of water, Q = flow through pipes and Hp = Head from pump

Now we have to use Bernoulli equation with pump head term in it as well as head loss

Z1 + P1/pg + V1^2/2g + Hp = Z2 + P2/pg + V2^2/2g + Hf

In this formula we assume that P1 ands P2 are atmospheric pressures at entry to the pump and exit of the nozzle, so P1 = P2 = 0

Z1 = 0 and Z2 = 3m

V1 = velocity in hoses and V2 = jet velocity from nozzle = 24m/s

We have to calculate velocity in hoses and then frictional head loss

From before v = V * (d2/D2) so v = 24 * (0.0375^2)/ (0.09872^2) = 3.463m/s so V1 = 3.463m/s 
Now we have to put V1 into frictional head loss formula Hf = 4  *f * L * v2/ D * 2g
so Hf = 4 * 0.007 * 45 * (3.463)^2 / (0.09872 * 19.62) = 7.80m

Now we have to put values in Bernoulli equation to find head from pump

so using Z1 + P1/pg + V1^2/2g + Hp = Z2 + P2/pg + V2^2/2g + Hf

0 + 0 + (3.463^2)/2g + Hp = 3 + 0 + (24^2)/2g + 7.8 Hp = 3 + (24^2)/2g + 7.8 - (3.463^2)/2g = 3 + 29.3578 + 7.8 - 0.611 Hp = 39.5468m

Flow from one hose Q = 1/4 Pi * D^2 * v = 1/4 * Pi * 0.09872^2 * 3.463 = 0.026507m^3/s

Power from one hose P = w * Q * Hp = 9810 * 0.026507 * 39.5468 = 10284W = 10.284kW as there are 2 hoses, total Power from hoses P = 10.284 * 2 = 20.567kW

**as the pump has an efficiency of 70 per cent then Power from pump = 20.567/ 0.7 = 29.382kW**

**IN MY TEXT BOOK THE ANSWER WAS GIVEN AS 31.1kW, IS THERE SOMETHING ELSE I SHOULD TAKE INTO CONSIDERATION?**

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat

I have fixed that now it should be V = Cv √ (2g * Hp) 
so that is from the nozzle the Jet Velocity V = Coefficent of Velocity * Square Root of (2g * Head at Nozzle).

I have actually found this https://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/subramanian/ch330/notes/Engineering%20Bernoulli%20Equation.pdf

On page 4 it says shaft work delivered by the pump to
the fluid accounts for the losses in the flow through the pipes and any fittings, the exit velocity head that must be delivered, and the lifting of the fluid from elevation z1 to elevation  z2 .

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat

Couldn't fit it all on previous reply
The lift of elevation (z2 - z1) = 3 m
Head Loss is from the pipe = 4 * f * L * v^2 / d * 2g
Isn't the exit velocity head from the jet velocity of the nozzle V^2 / 2g.

The problem I am having though, is that I think the jet velocity will be different than 24 m/s in part (a) because in part (a) there was no change in elevation.
However in part (b) there is a change in elevation of 3m

How can you calculate power when you don't know jet velocity?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat 
I don't know what to make of "You asked question before and someone bothered to format it for you" it comes across a bit tongue and cheek. 
This is same question as other post, problem was that I was trying to reply to prevost after I had done calculations because I was not getting answer, but I couldn't bloody reply to him.
Look we are all here aren't we to sort out our challenges with these questions.
I have put up with so much bloody nonsense to get correct answer for these questions. If you know someone that can help, then that will be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat

Can you please reply  to me regards to, if you know someone that understands this pump question.
I hope that you will reply to me on this, as I have made a big effort to get in touch with you regarding this already.

Also in my earlier reply I mentioned the resourceweb2.clarkson.edu/projects/subramanian/ch330/notes/… On page 4.
If you know someone that understands how I can relate that to my pump question then that will help.

Thanks
Robert

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat
I copied question across from my other post, problem was that formatting did not keep the same with mathjax and I did not notice it at the time, .
All you needed to say to me was can you please fix V=Cv2g∗Hp−−−−−−√. Using the word bothered sounds rude and makes it seem like I don't care about displaying my question, not the case, I'm not an expert in using mathjax yet.
My question is readable now.
You have not answered my question, if you know someone that understands this pump question, see even though you may not be interested you should be helpful and let me know.